# Can iPhone have "None" location - with GPS on

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am creating an app that uses a lot of gps location. If a user's phone settings allows for GPS, is it ever possible if their initial location is "
None"?

The reason I ask this is because when I simulate the app on the simulator, the default setting for location is "None" (Which causes some bugs). I want to know if these "None" locations only affect simulators or if they should be accounted for.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just handle the "None" locations gracefully and *know* that they're not a problem than to hope that they never occur in the wild?

Comment: When the user launches your app for the first time you have to ask their permission to access their location. If they deny permission then... you don’t get it.

Comment: I have a guard that requires them to permit location -- Let's assume they grant location permission

Comment: @Caleb this "None" location would need to be handled in multiple places -- I don't want to add unncessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** 
You have to handle this case.

A user can have an issue with his device **GPS** or not allow access to it or **GPS** takes time on load to get the first location for some reason.

You can't expect any **perfect scenario**, deal with **None**.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if these "None" locations only affect simulators or if they should be accounted for.

You should design your app to be able to tolerate not getting a location *even if* you're sure the device has the necessary hardware and the user permits the app to get location data. There will be times when the device simply can't get a location fix, or when the hardware fails, or the battery is so low that the system chooses not to turn on the radio, or whatever. You can't ensure that all the things that could go wrong won't, so make sure your app is prepared to handle problems.

> this "None" location would need to be handled in multiple places -- I don't want to add unncessary code

That sounds like a different problem. If you have more than one part of your app getting location data... why? Make location processing part of your app's data model. That way you're only receiving the location in one place, and you can handle problems in one place, and any other part of the app that needs the location data can get it without having to reimplement all that stuff.